# Apache POI - Parsing Dates with HSSFListener

Tags: java, excel, date, apache-poi, poi-hssf

First off, I'm working on using Apache POI's Event API using HSSFListener and XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler to read large files. So I'm not using a workbook where I can use some of the handy methods. I've already implemented it with that approach and got OOM errors.

For XLS files, I'm having trouble figuring out how to determine from a NumberRecord if the format is a Date format or Number format. I've looked at this old link ([Using Apache POI HSSFListener how to identify date type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835339/using-apache-poi-hssflistener-how-to-identify-date-type)) but only the Tika link works as the other no longer exists. It seems some modifications would work with the FormatTrackingHSSFListener but I'm missing something there.

I saw some people mentioning using the DateUtil to check if the value is in an InternalDateFormat like below, but that didn't work.

```
case NumberRecord.sid:
    NumberRecord numrec = (NumberRecord) record;
    if (DateUtil.isInternalDateFormat(numrec.getXFIndex())) {
        System.out.println("Cell found with date value " + DateUtil.getJavaDate(numrec.getValue())
                + " at row " + numrec.getRow() + " and column " + numrec.getColumn());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cell found with value " + numrec.getValue()
                + " at row " + numrec.getRow() + " and column " + numrec.getColumn());
    }
```

I wonder if the isADateFormat method would work (https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#isADateFormat-int-java.lang.String-) but I can't figure out what the formatString would be.

Thoughts? Much appreciated. The documentation is somewhat there but it's "fun" to get thru.

Comment: I've fixed the link in the older question to the Apache POI code, which is now at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/hssf/eventusermodel/XLS2CSVmra.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has issues with this, I've worked through this with the help from the [TIKA extractor](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/ExcelExtractor.java) link in the other question. I would suggest implementing an HSSFListener which itself has a FormatTrackingHSSFListener as a member variable. This will your initial listener and will capture all the formats (if I understand correctly), and it itself will have a child listener of your implementation.

```
public class YourListener implements HSSFListener {

    private SSTRecord sstRecord;
    private FormatTrackingHSSFListener formatListener;
    private List<String> sheetNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private Integer currentSheetIndex = -1;
    private Integer rowCount = 0;

    public YourListener() {
        this.formatListener = new FormatTrackingHSSFListener(this);
    }
}
```

When you override processRecord, your switch for the NumberRecord.sid can call the formatListener's formatNumberDateCell. So something like:

```
case NumberRecord.sid: // Contains a numeric cell value
     NumberRecord number = (NumberRecord) record;
     System.out.println(record, formatListener.formatNumberDateCell(number));
     break;
```